# how to bulk insert from backtickcsv file into a table in h2 database?

Tags: h2

I have a .backtickcsv file in my local machine, from which i want to insert data into a table in h2,

```
String sql = "BULK INSERT "+tableName+" FROM '"+fileName+"' WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'char',FIELDTERMINATOR = '"+separator+"',ROWTERMINATOR = '`\r\n', KEEPNULLS );";
```

when i run the above query in my code i am getting the error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement BULK[*]
>   INSERT EMPLOYEE FROM
>   'C:\test\41bbaee5_e610_4796_a240_d37402b9f8e6.backticksv' WITH
>   (DATAFILETYPE = 'char',FIELDTERMINATOR = '`',ROWTERMINATOR = '` ',
>   KEEPNULLS );; expected BACKUP, BEGIN, {; SQL statement:

how can i solve this?

Comment: What in the [h2 manual](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html) made you think that BULK INSERT was valid syntax in h2?

Comment: good that you made me realize no such bulk insert in h2, But is there any way i could achieve this kind of insert? @a_horse_with_no_name